# Delta and Gamma profile

Tags: delta, gamma, spread-options

There is an active `spread option` traded in ICS as described here - https://www.theice.com/products/28881205/Crude-Future-Brent-1-Month-Calendar-Spread-Options

I am interested to know the `Delta` and `Gamma` profile of such `Calendar spread option` w.r.t. various possible underlying spread values.

Is there any empirical study for such calendar spread option?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A calendar spread is nothing more than a short call and long call with TTM_1 and TTM_2. If you can find the quotes of those underlying options; you can retrieve the IV and hence the greeks.